# insert std::map in std::map

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, xcode4.2

I have a container of `std::map<string,std::map<string,int>>`.

1. How do I insert data into such a container? Do I have to have an inner map as additional variable or not? The code should compile under both MSVC 2010 and XCode 4.2 (Snow Leopard).
2. Is XCode 4.2 under Snow Leopard (10.6) supports such a container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the overloaded `[]` operator and you are done:

```
std::map<string,std::map<string,int> > data;
data["foo"]["bar"] = 10;
```

and yes, Xcode 4.2 supports them, I personally used them under OSX with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple answer you need to have a temporary map:

```
std::map<string, int> tempMap;
std::string tempString;
```

Then you will need to insert these into the above map once they have been set.

```
tempMap.insert(std::pair<string, std::map<string, int>>(tempString, tempMap))
```

Then you can access them as in Jacks answer.

Comment: There is no need I guess to have a temporary map, whenever you use the `[]`, if element doesn't exist, it is automatically created hence you don't have to insert any temporary map (unless you need to insert something already filled)

Comment: @Jack Thanks, i guess this is just a different way of doing it then.